# How to get Updates from Channel which we have joined but not interacting with Twilio Chat SDK?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio Chat SDK and building 1-1 chat application by creating a private channel between people. Now the moment I have more than 1 private channel, is there a way to know if someone has messaged me on another channel? To be precise I want to know if there is a listener in Twilio JS SDK which can tell me whenever there is an update on any channel I have joined so that I can show on the UI that there is a new message on another channel?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In this case I would make sure you had [joined all the channels](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/Channel.html#join__anchor) and then listen to the [`messageAdded` events on each of the channels](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/Channel.html#event:messageAdded). You wouldn't have to display the channels, just keep the registrations in the background.

I haven't had time to test this (I'm about to board a plane) but there is a [`messageAdded` event on the `Client` object too](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.4/docs/Client.html#event:messageAdded) which you may be able to use for messages arriving to any channel.

Let me know if that helps at all.